# What are the differences between MikTeX and TeXLive?

Tags: windows, latex, miktex, texlive

Under Windows, what differences are visible to the user? If you are already familiar with one (MikTeX in my case), is it worth it to try out the other?

Comment: You can find some differences mentioned here:

["What are the advantages of TeX Live over MiKTeX?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had MikTeX in Windows, and I just "migrated" to a Mac and installed TeXLive. As far as I am aware there is no difference, at least nothing you would notice, because it is all LaTeX.

Different distributions, however, will come with different things in the bundle, as for example different editors. The choice of editor, rather than the choice of distribution, is the important and interesting question, as the editor is the thing that will make things look and feel different. But you don't need to install a new distribution to get the extras, they can all be downloaded separately.

In summary: there is no point in trying a different distribution; if you want to try new things, try a different editor  :)